# Restrict Android Widget to one instance per device

Tags: android, android-widget

How could I restrict Android widgets in a way that only one instance can be created by the user at all times?

A possible way is to store a `SharedPreference` including a `counter` variable and crash, if the count is 1, but obviously I'm not in favor of that solution. ;-)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> How could I restrict Android widgets in a way that only one instance can be created by the user at all times?

You can't.

However, just because the user asks for multiple instances of your app widget does not mean you have to manage separate data for each. Just ignore the IDs and use the `updateAppWidget()` method that does not take any IDs.

Comment: @CommonsWare - do you have any idea how to send a generic broadcast, without any WidgetIds? Because I'm having certain signals from a `Service`, and don't want to mix the service operations with Widget / View code.

Comment: @Sebastian Roth: I cannot read your second comment due to the long string in your first comment. Consider deleting that first comment, or editing your question, or something.

Comment: @CommonsWare, done. Actually I have found a way now. In abstract: Define a counter variable, add a android:configure activity and manage the widget. If it's already visible (counter == 1), then use `AppWidgetHost ah = new AppWidgetHost(this, 1024); ah.deleteAppWidgetId(mAppWidgetId);`. 1024 is the magic number for the Android Launcher. That configuration activity could be transparent or without any view at all, but it could do anything we need to prepare.

Comment: @Sebastian Roth: It is unlikely that your code will work across multiple devices, as I doubt that `1024` is a "magic number" for each and every home screen implementation. Also, AFAIK, you should not have permissions to do that on hardware -- if you do, that's a security hole that I will try to get fixed. Please allow your users to have as many instances of your app widget as they wish, even if all of them have the same content.

Comment: Ok, go ahead. It's confirmed to work on HTC Desire (2.2) and Samsung Galaxy (2.2). Will try to use the solution you propose. I'd love to trade this `thing` for a proper solution in `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4561700/widgets-configured-with-androidconfigure-will-receive-onupdate-even-if-configura` if that is even possible ;-)) . I found **1024** in Launcher.java#161: `static final int APPWIDGET_HOST_ID = 1024;`

Comment: @Sebastian Roth: With respect to `1024`, not every home screen uses `Launcher.java`. With respect to that other SO question, Android changed the rules of app widget configuration a year or so ago, and I just haven't taken the time to try to sort through all the combinations as yet. With respect to the security hole, I'll do some more experiments in a week or so, post-New Year's. Right now, you need an app widget instance ID to do much damage. `AppWidgetManager` lets you get IDs for a `ComponentName`, and if that's not adequately secured, an app could delete any app widget it wants from anyone.

Comment: Ok. Understand. So have a happy new year first. :-)

Comment: @Sebastian Roth: FYI, the security hole I was concerned about seems to be OK. One app cannot get another app's app widget IDs from the `AppWidgetManager`.

Comment: @Commonsware But u could bruteforce from 0 to 200?

Answer (score 1):

I do like this:

On Widget onUpdate method when user create first widget I save the ID of widget and update widget, for second time when onUpdate is called ( when added widget is updated ) then I check for the same id of widget and update it else tell the user that only one widget is allowed.

```
 @Override
    public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int[] appWidgetIds) {

        for (int appWidgetId : appWidgetIds) {

            //TinyDb is SharedPreferences Class
            TinyDB tinydb = new TinyDB(context);
            int WidgetId= tinydb.getInt("WidgetID",-1);

            //Check if WidgetID is same as Added ID if yes UPDATE
            if (WidgetId == appWidgetId){
                updateAppWidget(context, appWidgetManager, appWidgetId);
                return;
            //Check if no widget is added then add widget and save widget ID to sharedPreferences
            } else if (WidgetId == -1){
                tinydb.putInt("WidgetID", appWidgetId);
                updateAppWidget(context, appWidgetManager, appWidgetId);
                return;
            }
            else
                {
                //Make toast to tell the user that only one widget is allowed
                Toast.makeText(context, context.getResources().getString(R.string.Only_one_widget_allowed), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
        }
    }
```

**And don't forget:** if user remove all widgets to save it to shared preferences, I use int -1 so I use this code:

```
  @Override
    public void onDisabled(Context context) {
        // Enter relevant functionality for when the last widget is disabled
            TinyDB tinydb = new TinyDB(context);
            tinydb.putInt("WidgetID", -1);
    }
```

and it works like a charm! Wholaa!