# Dynamically deleting Android Widget from home screen

Tags: android, android-widget

I need to delete a home screen widget instance after I press back from a Configuration Activity, since I want it to be totally removed, and not to be left in the "limbo" as a consequence of [issue 2539](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=2539). So It would be nice one of these fixes:

1. Fix issue 2539 and let widget instances gracefully disappear both from homescreen and from "limbo"
2. Let programmers do this trough the AppWidgetHost with the right id refering to the home screen, ( making this security holes proof). (Interesting attempt described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4552505/restrict-android-widget-to-one-instance-per-device/) )

Right now is any of these possible ?

Answer (score 1):

I solved on my own, dealing with just two Boolean flags.
Here is what i did on the class extending AppWidgetProvider

```
public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager,
        int[] appWidgetIds) {
    super.onUpdate(context, appWidgetManager, appWidgetIds);
    SharedPreferences settings = context.getSharedPreferences(SHARED_PREFERENCES, 0); 

    for(int widgetId:appWidgetIds)
    {   
        boolean configured = settings.getBoolean(CONFIGURED_PREFERENCE+widgetId, false);    //In order to skip initial UpdateService
        boolean widget= settings.getBoolean(WIDGET_PREFERENCE+widgetId, false);
         if(!widget && configured) continue;   // In order to skip phantom Widgets update


    if(!configured)
    {   

     SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
     editor.putBoolean(CONFIGURED_PREFERENCE+widgetId, true);
           editor.commit();
        }
    else
    {    Intent updateService=new Intent(context, UpdateService.class);          
        updateService.putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID,widgetId);
         context.startService(updateService);
    }   


  }

}
```

Comment: links seems to be broken