# Stop user from making multiple instances of app widget

Tags: android, widget

I have made an widget of my application. Currently user can create multiple instances of the same widget on the home screen. I don't want the user to make multiple instances of the same widget on home screen. Any suggestions ? Thanx in advance.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4552505/restrict-android-widget-to-one-instance-per-device

Comment: @MortezaSoleimani, next time, please vote to close the question as duplicate. Thanks.

Answer (score -3):

The concept is called Singleton. look it up ;)